# VB.NET - How to move to next item a For Each Loop?

Tags: vb.net, loops

Is there a statment like `Exit For`, except instead of exiting the loop it just moves to the next item.

**For example:**

```
For Each I As Item In Items

    If I = x Then 
        ' Move to next item
    End If

    ' Do something

Next
```

I know could simply add an `Else` to the If statement so it would read as follows:

```
For Each I As Item In Items

    If I = x Then 
        ' Move to next item
    Else
        ' Do something
    End If

Next
```

Just wondering if there is a way to jump to the next item in the `Items` list. I'm sure most will properly be asking why not just use the `Else` statement, but to me wrapping the "Do Something" code seems to be less readable. Especially when there is a lot more code.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

```
For Each I As Item In Items
    If I = x Then Continue For

    ' Do something
Next
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i was looking for, funny how its not in the MSDN documentation?? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) Also congrats on beating Jon to the post, by a whole 20 seconds! :)

Comment: You'd better close the `If` statement properly. It is misleading.

Answer (score 55):

I'd use the `Continue` statement instead:

```
For Each I As Item In Items

    If I = x Then
        Continue For
    End If

    ' Do something

Next
```

Note that this is slightly different to moving the iterator itself on - anything before the `If` will be executed again. Usually this is what you want, but if not you'll have to use `GetEnumerator()` and then `MoveNext()`/`Current` explicitly rather than using a `For Each` loop.

Answer (score 6):

What about:

```
If Not I = x Then

  ' Do something '

End If

' Move to next item '
```

Answer (score 1):

**I want to be clear that the following code is not good practice.** You can use GOTO Label:

```
For Each I As Item In Items

    If I = x Then
       'Move to next item
        GOTO Label1
    End If

    ' Do something
    Label1:
Next
```

Comment: You could, but please don't.

Comment: Due to jump, therefore it is bad.

Comment: If it's not good practice, and there is a clearly better solution that the language supports (Continue For / Resume Next), maybe this answer should be voluntarily removed.

Comment: Stackoverflow allows multiple answers for the purpose of exploring the range of options available. I agree this is a bad option, but it's an option. So I think it's worthy of being included for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried `Continue For` it Failed, I got a compiler error. While doing this, I discovered 'Resume':

```
For Each I As Item In Items

    If I = x Then
       'Move to next item
       Resume Next
    End If

    'Do something

Next
```

Note: I am using VBA here.

Comment: This code doesn't even work in VBA. `Resume Next` is for unstructured error handling.

Comment: You have to use a big IF statement to wrap the whole end of the loop in VBA because there is no continue statement. So `If I <> x Then`

Answer (score 0):

Only the "Continue For" is an acceptable standard (the rest leads to "spaghetti code").

At least with "continue for" the programmer knows the code goes directly to the top of the loop.

For purists though, something like this is best since it is pure "non-spaghetti" code.

```
Dim bKeepGoing as Boolean 
For Each I As Item In Items
  bKeepGoing = True
  If I = x Then
    bKeepGoing = False
  End If
  if bKeepGoing then
    ' Do something
  endif
Next
```

For ease of coding though, "Continue For" is OK. (Good idea to comment it though).

Using "Continue For"

```
For Each I As Item In Items
  If I = x Then
    Continue For   'skip back directly to top of loop
  End If
  ' Do something
Next
```