# Way to Jump to Next i in For..Next Loop?

Tags: vb.net, quickbasic

I'm reverse engineering in QuickBasic and I have code like this:

```
FOR i = star TO fin
   IF a < 1 THEN 
    CALL clrbot
    COLOR 15
    PRINT force$(side); " army in "; city$(armyloc(i)); " is CUT OFF !";
    TICK turbo!
    GOTO alone
   END IF
   size = size + 1
   max = 11: IF LEN(armyname$(i)) < 11 THEN max = LEN(armyname$(i))
   mtx$(size) = LEFT$(armyname$(i), max)
   array(size) = i
alone:
NEXT i
```

I'd like to get rid of the line label (alone) and instead do something like:

```
   IF a < 1 THEN 
     CALL clrbot
    COLOR 15
    PRINT force$(side); " army in "; city$(armyloc(i)); " is CUT OFF !";
    TICK turbo!
    NEXT i
   END IF
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET - How to move to next item a For Each Loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829689/vb-net-how-to-move-to-next-item-a-for-each-loop)

Comment: You can use Continue For to skip to the next iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the GOTO with an Else:

```
For i = star To Fin
    If a < 1 Then
        ' Do something
    Else
        ' Do Something else
    End If
Next
```

This would follow the same logic - the `Else` takes the place of the `GOTO alone` statement.

In the original code (QuickBASIC) if the `If` block is entered, everything after then `GOTO alone` statement is ignored.

If the `If` block is not entered (i.e., a >= 1) then everything after the `If` block is executed.

The `Else` statement in the VB.NET code will produce the same behavior.  If a < 1, the first block will be executed and the `Else` block will be ignored, and the loop will advance to the next increment of `i`.

If a >= 1, then the `Else` block will be executed and the loop will then advance to the next increment of `i`.

The above assumes labels in QuickBASIC are like labels in DOS batch files.